# how to make unnumbered sections aligned in table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I have the following code to create table of contents:

```
     \documentclass{article}

     \begin{document}

     \tableofcontents

     \section{section A}

     \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{section B}
     \section*{section B}

     \end{document}
```

Section B does appear in the TOC, but it appears unaligned with the text from section A, because there is no number preceding it. Is there a way to make section B go forward a bit, so that it is aligned?

EDIT: I would rather have someone that is "truly" aligned, instead of pushing it forward with blank spaces...

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc with option `indentunnumbered` should do the trick just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the little package [unnumberedtotoc](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc) which can be found on github at the moment.  It just provides one option which will suit your needs; `indentunnumbered`. 
It also takes care or your marks. All this functionality is provided by the KOMA-classes by default. A switch might be worth it ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[indentunnumbered]{unnumberedtotoc}%<-----
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{section A}

\addsec{section B}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this seems to work, but unfortunately breaks hyperref in the TOC. Any ideas (clicking on an numbered section goes back to the beginning of the document, instead of the right page)?

Comment: No problem here, did you load my package *before* loading hyperref? EDIT: It ieven works when loaded after, just checked with the above example (extended by some blindtext).

Comment: @kloop Are there any news concerning hyperlinks?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for ... but it seems not to work with amsbook documentclass.  I encounter two issues: 1. the documentclass itself adds unnumbered sections to the toc, so entries are doubled (one with indent, one without); 2. Really I want to have unnumbered subsubsections with the correct indent, and it seems there is no \addsubsubsec command similar to \addsec.  Any possible fix or workaround you can think of?  Thanks.

Comment: Hi @chris. The little package is unsuited for ams classes. It is worth asking a new question about it.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks, I have asked this as a new question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622874/indent-unnumbered-sections-in-toc-for-ams-classes

Answer (score 5):

You can add horizontal spacing equivalent to what would normally be added:

[image]

### Notes:

- The `\addcontentsline` should be immediately *after* the `\section*{}`, *not before* the `\section{}`.

### Code:

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \begin{document}

 \tableofcontents

 \section{section A}

 \section*{section B}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\hphantom{\numberline{\thesection}}section B}

 \section{section C}
 
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Just `\protect\numberline{}` is sufficient.

Comment: the issue with that is that it doesn't add a pointer to the page number...

Comment: Tip for the `hyperref` package users with `bookmarksnumbered` option: `\protect\numberline{}` produces an unwanted leading whitespace in the `.out` file, hence in bookmark as well. `\texorpdfstring{\protect\numberline{}foo}{foo}` will help (`hyperref` isn't related to the original question but just in case someone in the future refers to this answer).

Answer (score 1):

You have to push that entry by `\@pnumwidth` which is the width reserved for typsetting the section numbers in toc.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \newlength{\mylen}
 \makeatletter
 \setlength{\mylen}{\@pnumwidth}
 \makeatother
 \begin{document}

 \tableofcontents

 \section{section A}


 \section*{section B}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\hspace*{\mylen}section B}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this didn't work for me on the actual document, though it could be because it is entangled with something else.... also, it doesn't add a pointer to the page number.