# unnumbered sections aligned, including pdfborderstyle, in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, indentation, border

Thanks to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212439/22939) I manged to get my unnumbered sections aligned in table of contents, but as I'm using [hyperref](/questions/tagged/hyperref) to highlight `pdfborderstyle` I get an outline, or highlight, that is not indented. Like this (code below),

[image: JESUS]

is there a way to indent to that the `pdfborderstyle` get's indented, i.e. stops at the blue line? If that makes sense.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
            \hypersetup{pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1} % thanks, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26085/22939
}
 \begin{document}
 \tableofcontents

 \chapter{Introduction}
 \chapter*{Main point}
 \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\hphantom{\numberline{\thesection}}Main point}
 \chapter{Some additional material}

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work with your code (which by the way is too complicated, there is no need for `\hphantom`, an empty `\numberline` would do the same thing:
`\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Main point}`)

You will have to define a new contentline type:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
            \hypersetup{pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1} % thanks, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26085/22939
}
\makeatletter
\def\toclevel@schapter{0}
\newcommand*\l@schapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip\numberline{}%
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother  
 \begin{document}
 \tableofcontents

 \chapter{Introduction}
 \chapter*{Main point}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{schapter}{Main point}
 \chapter{Some additional material}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is my last +1. Very good and I send you a greeting.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. There's still something with where it links to that is kinda strange. When I click **Introduction** and **Some additional material** from the document TOC, and from the pdf-viewer's TOC, I am _sent to_ the top of the page, but clicking **Main point**, both places, send me to _the middle_ of the page where **Main point** is at the top. Is it possible to anchor the `\addcontentsline`, or what it is, to the top of the page in the same way that  **Introduction** and **Some additional material** is anchored?

Comment: Remove the manual \phantomsection.